# Relacionamento entre estado, cidade, municipio e distrito

Tags: mysql, modelo-relacional

Baixei um arquivo xml do IBGE com dados de estados, cidades, municipios e distritos. Fiz a separação para 4 tabelas e fiz seus relacionamentos.

**[Segue o SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b92632/5)**

A minha dúvida é:

- Esta certo esse relacionamento que fiz?
- Tem como melhorar ainda usando MySQL?

Fiz uma view para ficar mais prático a busca de dados com a query exibida.

- Essa query tem como melhorar ou já esta bom?
- E quando coloco um `order by nome_estado, nome_cidade, nome_municipio, nome_distrito`, com os dados que tenho (um total de 10302) essa query passa de 0,006s (uma média) para 0,356s (tbm uma média), isso por causa do order by. Tem como melhorar essa ordenação?

Segue a query em si:

```
select  e.id as estado_id, e.nome as nome_estado,
        c.id as cidade_id, c.nome as nome_cidade,
        m.id as municipio_id, m.nome as nome_municipio,
        d.id as distrito_id, d.nome as nome_distrito
from distrito d
join municipio m ON m.id = d.municipio_id
join cidade c ON c.id = m.cidade_id
join estado e ON e.id = c.estado_id
```

Comment: Você poderia me dizer o link onde baixou esse XML? Estou precisando bastante e não estou encontrando.

Comment: @MarcioSimao o link onde tem a base é esse aqui http://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/Download/Download.ashx?u=geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_territorial/divisao_territorial/2013/dtb_2013.zip é de 2013, mas foi o mais atual que achei.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno! Você sabe se existe alguma tabela com a relação de bairros de cada cidade?

Comment: Dai já não sei não, mas acho que o mais próximo se olhar essa tabela é o Nome_Distrito. Aqui onde trabalho já serviu e falaram que não precisaria mais do que isso

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente falta índice nos nomes para melhorar a performance:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cidade` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `estado_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `nome` (`nome`),
   KEY `estado_id` (`estado_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `distrito` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `municipio_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `nome` (`nome`),
   KEY `municipio_id` (`municipio_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `estado` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `sigla` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `nome` (`nome`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `municipio` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `cidade_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `nome` (`nome`),
   KEY `cidade_id` (`cidade_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

No caso, você poderia também fazer o join começando pelo Estado, e seguindo a mesma sequência do ORDER, mas ao pré-processar sua query, de qualquer forma o BD pode fazer a otimização.

Eu provavelmente faria a query assim, mantendo a ordem parecida com o resultado:

```sql
SELECT
   e.id   AS estado_id,
   e.nome AS estado_nome,
   c.id   AS cidade_id,
   c.nome AS cidade_nome,
   m.id   AS municipio_id,
   m.nome AS municipio_nome,
   d.id   AS distrito_id,
   d.nome AS distrito_nome
FROM estado e
LEFT JOIN cidade c ON c.estado_id = e.id
LEFT JOIN municipio m ON m.cidade_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN distrito d ON d.municipio_id = m.id
ORDER BY e.nome,c.nome,m.nome,d.nome
```

O Execution Plan da minha e da sua query são relativamente parecidos, mas tem alguma diferença. O index, por sua vez, pode dar uma ajuda maior.

> [**SQL Fiddle** atualizado](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/383bc5/1)

Comment: Valew, vou dar uma olhada melhor nisso e assim que tiver uma resposta melhor já comento. Quanto ao nome no select foi falha minha de digitação só, mas valew mesmo.

Comment: Então, fiz as alterações aqui e fiz os testes. Mesmo colocando os nomes do campos como index não alterou muito o tempo da busca, e também alterei a ordem (mesmo não alterando muito o produto, não custa né). Mas valew pela ajuda. O que queria mais saber era se eu estava fazendo algo muito errado mesmo, mas já achava que não e analisando vejo que não estou tão errado assim.